# Почему C++ позволяет вызывать деструктор константного объекта вручную?

Tags: c++, const, деструктор

Скажите, пожалуйста, в чем заключается причина того, что язык позволяет вызвать деструктор для константного члена (вручную)? Ведь деструктор меняет состояние объекта. Причем, не только состояние удаляемого объекта, но и состояние объекта-владельца.

```
class Composition
{
    public:
    // ...
    const Object object;
};

// ...

Composition composition;
composition.object.~Object();
```

Comment: Язык обеспечивает гибкость, которая может казаться и излишним, но вполне может быть ситуация, что вы захотите использовать память, занимаемым данным объектом, для записи другой информации. Для этого нужно вызвать деструкторы всех объектов, содержащегося в нем, а для этого вызывается просто деструктор данного объекта. Это может пригодится для  какого то особого распределителя памяти

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандарт:

> A destructor is used to destroy objects of its class type. A
>   destructor takes no parameters, and no return type can be specified
>   for it (not even void). The address of a destructor shall not be
>   taken. A destructor shall not be static. A destructor can be invoked
>   for a **const**, **volatile** or **const volatile** object. A destructor shall not
>   be declared **const**, **volatile** or **const volatile** (9.3.2). **const** and
>   **volatile** semantics (7.1.6.1) are not applied on an object under
>   destruction. They stop being in effect when the destructor for the
>   most derived object (1.8) starts. A destructor shall not be declared
>   with a ref-qualifier.

Перевод:

> Деструктор используется для уничтожения объектов своего типа.
>   Деструктор не принимает параметров, и для него нельзя указать тип
>   возвращаемого значения (даже void). Адрес деструктора не берется.
>   Деструктор не должен быть статичным. Деструктор может быть вызван для
>   объекта типа **const**, **volatile** или **const volatile**. Деструктор не должен
>   быть объявлен как **const**, **volatile** или **const volatile** (9.3.2).
>   семантика **const** и **volatile** (7.1.6.1) не применяется к разрушаемому
>   объекту. Они перестают действовать, когда запускается деструктор для
>   самого производного объекта (1.8). Деструктор не должен быть объявлен
>   с ref-квалификатором.

Логика простая, у объекта жизнь когда-нибудь заканчивается. Даже у константного.

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -Wall constdestr2.cpp
#include <new>
class C{
public :
  C(int x):i{x}{}
  C(C const && c):i{std::move(c.i)}{}
  ~C(){}
private :
  int i ;
};

int main(){
  // память где-то далеко
  char mem [ sizeof ( C ) ] ;
  // ручное создание константного объекта
  C const * c = new ( mem ) C { 7 } ;
  // выделяем новую память
  char mem2 [ sizeof ( C ) * 2 ] ;
  // перенос константного объекта
  C const * c2 = new ( mem2 ) C { std ::  move  ( * c ) } ;
  // ручное удаление константы
  c -> ~ C ( ) ;
  // теперь вектор констант в другом месте
  // ручное удаление константы
  c2 -> ~ C ( ) ;
}
```

Здесь пример увеличения размера массива константных объектов. Где каждый объект нуждается в переносе : конструктор переноса и вызов деструктора.

Comment: Для размещения объекта в буфере у него должен быть тип массив unsigned char или массив std::byte.

Comment: Не знаю кто кому что должен. Жизнь подсказала, что один байт это : `char`,`unsigned char`,`signed char`,`uint8_t`,`int8_t`. А `std::byte` - это уже выпендрёж C++. @user7860670

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что размещение в буфере c типом массив char является неопределенным поведением.

Comment: Ведь вопрос не касается  управлению динамической памятью. Вопрос о вызове деструктора содержащегося  объекта.

Answer (score 1):

[Отсюда](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor):

> The purpose of the destructor is to free the resources that the object may have acquired during its lifetime.
>
> Note that calling a destructor directly for an ordinary object, such as a local variable, invokes undefined behavior when the destructor is called again, at the end of scope.

---

> Задача деструктора - освободить ресурсы, которые он может захватить в процессе жизни.
>
> Заметьте, что вызов деструктора напрямую для простого объекта, такого как локальная переменная, приводит к неопределенному поведению, когда деструктор будет вызван при выходе из области видимости.

Деструктор - специальный метод класса, должен вызываться один раз. Он не меняет состояние объекта. Он его разрушает. Поэтому к нему не применяется семантика const и volatile (как верно заметил AlexGlebe).

В примере дважды произойдет вызов деструктора (напрямую и при выходе из области видимости) и UB в качестве результата.

P.S. Если язык позволяет разыменовать нулевой указатель, то это не значит, что так можно делать.

Comment: Тут нет ответа на вопрос.